# В Visual Studio долго запускается отладка

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, отладка

На ПК стоит Visual Studio 2015.

ПК не сказать, что бы очень мощный: Старенький i5 650 и 8гб ОЗУ, Win7, но должен справляться с задачей быстро.

На то, что бы запустить WCF службу + WinForm приложение в режиме Debug  уходит около 1 минуты. 
Приложения достаточно простые, а их Build (Без Debug) происходит, почти, моментально.

В чем может быть проблема?

Пробовал CCleaner'ом все зачищать, дефрагментировать диск, но не помогло.

VS не нагружена расширениями, стоит только ReSharper.

Comment: Антивирус? У меня была похожая проблема, решилось все переустановкой антивируса

Comment: Подтягиваются символы для всех используемых компонентов. Можно попробовать настроить локальный сервер символов, но не факт что поможет.

Comment: А как это сделать? Например, дома у меня все прекрасно дебажится. Правда, там процессор i7

Comment: Ну, кто его знает, в чём проблема. Экспортируйте настройки в .vssettings на обоих машинах и сравните. Или может быть у вас там медленный винчестер.